# unable to remove a softwere complacently

Tags: uninstall, eclipse, software-uninstall, reinstall

i had a very big problem.i had installed eclipse few days ago but now i want to reinstall it .when i uninstall it , it uninstalls (not fully, i had to type apt autoremove for it and then it disappears from dash and launcher)but when i typed apt install eclipse  it installs without any downloads and all my previous settings and the bug due to which i had done this still remains the same its like it was never been uninstalled.

i really want to know why this happence
[as you can see in screen shot that after i hit enter,it dosent downloads but starts ti install immediately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1eOd.png)

pls edit my answer to display the screenshot that i have entered ,you cant see it due to my low reputation.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge PACKAGENAME ; sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ; sudo apt-get clean`. That will purge (uninstall and delete global configuration) the specified package, purge all not yet automatically removed, but no longer required dependencies and finally clean your local package cache. Maybe you also have to inspect the hidden files and folders in your home directory to find user-specific configuration files that will not get removed by purging the package.

Comment: thanks. it works.u should put this in answer so it can help others

Comment: @smitpatil Feel free to post the answer yourself, if nobody else does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ...

- ```
  sudo apt-get purge PACKAGENAME
  ```

  to purge (uninstall and delete global configuration) the specified package, ...
- ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
  ```

  to purge all not yet automatically removed, but no longer required dependencies, and ...
- ```
  sudo apt-get clean
  ```

  to finally clean your local package cache and delete all downloaded `.deb` package files. This does not uninstall anything, it just removes the files it automatically downloads and caches when you install anything.

Maybe you additionally have to inspect the hidden files and folders in your home directory to find user-specific configuration files that will not get removed by purging the package.